# What are the characteristics of kerala mAntrikam?

Tags: mantras, tradition, agamas, tantra

It is lesser known fact that the tantra flourished in southern India in the state of Kerala. Like that of Kashmir and Bengal.

Kerela tantrism is also specialised and is called as kerala mantrikam or kerala mantravaadam.

What are main features of this ?

Are there any lineages or scripture related to this ?

Comment: Amazingly all the Tantra places seem cursed now - Kashmir, Kerala & WB!

Comment: @Rakesh Kerala mantravaadam or mantrik usually worship Devils. They use their powers to help the villagers or whoever goes to them in exchange of money. I don't know Mantrikam (person who does rituals through mantra) still exists. But they don't worship gods or deities. They have their own Puja style as per their scriptures. I don't know tantra has devil worshipping Scriptures. But if you are asking about godly scriptures then mantravaadam is not the case.

Comment: @Salvation no it's not true.yes they have own process but whole mantrikam is not based on what you say. Its wide subject

Comment: @Rakesh I don't know if mantrikam is related to god, but if you go there and ask anyone about mantrikam, then they will only think about these things. If you are talking about Tantra related to gods, then I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: @Rakesh I can be wrong also. But just keep it in mind and use the right words, like satvik tantra or mantravaadam related to gods when asking to south India people.

Comment: @Salvation mantrikam.may have devil related stuff but its not mainly the case as you said. See this link and see its rituals http://keralatanthra.blogspot.ca/2013/03/bhagavathi-seva.html?m=1

Comment: There is nothing like satvik or tamasika tantra. There are lot of myths related to tantra. For this we have a chat room dedicated for agama shastra and tantra you can have discussion on tantra there

Comment: This blog is by a Naamboodri means a Kerala Brahmin and it is related to Devi Puja. Yes it is pure satvik Tantra.

Comment: @Salvation its also kerala.mAntrikam and kutti chatan also kerela mAntrikam.

Comment: @Rakesh lol kutti Chattan is devil.

Comment: @Salvation that is what i am saying if you read my comments. Based on kutti chattan you saying it but its vast subject and has many high deities and sadhana but in general tantra is misunderstood among the masses

Comment: @Rakesh ok now clear, yes satvik tantra in Kerala has a different type of worship. If you go to Devi temple in Kerala and same type of Devi temple in some other place,  you will find noticeable difference, even an beginner like mine can know that

Comment: @Salvation yes kerela temples follow uniqueness agama process for temples than rest of India. Temple priest usually called tantri.

Comment: @Rakesh Ok yes they are called Tantri.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. exactly. It seems all places where tantra used to reign like Bengal,Kashmir and Kerala (even Assam to an extant) are cursed now. Which really makes me wonder about tantric paths as a whole. Even tibet followed tantric paths almost similar to Hinduism.

Comment: @user13155 is kutti chattan a deity in kerala or an evil spirit?

Comment: @RishX considered deity in kerala

Comment: @RakeshJoshi i can't find any information about this deity. Is this a local village deity or a form of Vedic Gods?

Comment: @RishX obviously it is local. Search kutti chattan or vishnu maya